# De Rham Theorem for other coefficients

Tags: analysis, homology-cohomology

Are there versions of De Rham's theorem for which the coefficients are not just $\mathbb{R}$? In particular, is there a vector-valued version of De Rham's theorem?

Comment: Have you tried using the universal coefficient theorem + de Rham's theorem?

Comment: I tried. I am particularly interested in coefficients in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I reached the conclusion that it should work because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is free, and therefore $Tor$ should vanish. I'm not really sure how to make sense of this - are we integrating vector-valued forms somehow?

Comment: You're getting close! The coefficients for ordinary homology and cohomology lie in an abelian group; in particular, it only refers to the abelian group structure on R^n. You see from the UCT that taking coefficients in R^n is isomorphic to taking coefficients in R. De Rham's theorem says this is isomorphic to the usual de Rham cohomology.